# Trigger Submit event of Angular Form from Parent

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a child component which has a reactive form and from parent when I click on submit, I want it to trigger submit functionality which includes validations on submit.

**parentComponent**

```
export class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChild('childComponent') childComponent: ChildComponent
  
  submit(): void {
     this.childForm.triggerSubmit();
  }
}
```

**parent Html**

```
<child-component #childComponent></child-component>
<input type="button" value="submit" (click)="submit()">
```

**childComponent**

```
export class ChildComponent {
  @ViewChild('myForm') myForm: NgForm;
  myFormGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.initializeForm();
  }

  initializeForm(): void {
    this.myFormGroup = this.fb.group(
      {
        name: ['', { validator: Validators.required}]
      }, { updateOn: 'submit' }
    );
  }

  submitForm() {
    console.log(this.myFormGroup.value);
  }

  triggerSubmit() {
     this.myForm.ngSubmit.emit();
  }
}
```

**childComponent Html**

```
<form
#myForm="ngForm"
[formGroup]="myFormGroup"
(submit)="submitForm()"
>
<label for="float-input-name">Device Name</label> <br />
<input
   formControlName="name"
   id="float-input-name"
   type="text"
   />
<ng-container
   *ngIf="
   myFormGroup.get('name')?.invalid &&
   myFormGroup.get('name')?.errors &&
   (myFormGroup.get('name')?.dirty || myFormGroup.get('name')?.touched)
   "
   >
   <small
      class="text-danger block"
      *ngIf="myFormGroup.get('name')?.hasError('required')"
      >
   This field is required.
   </small>
</ng-container>
</form>
```

triggerSubmit method is called but submit event of form is not getting triggered. Once it gets triggered, ideally submitForm method should be triggered. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **child-component** html you should change event name to `(submit)` to `(ngSubmit)`

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" [formGroup]="myFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" >
....
</form>
```